# You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "convolution2d_1" with a weight list of length 32, but the layer was expecting 2 weights

Tags: python, 深層学習, keras

kerasを使って学習済みモデルの評価をしようとしています。しかし、重みを設定するとタイトルのようなエラーが出てしまいました。フィルタ数、つまり最初のnOutoutPlaneは32なのでweightsの数も32になると考えましたがなぜ2になるのでしょうか。

**エラー**

```
You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "convolution2d_1" with a  weight list of length 32, but the layer was expecting 2 weights.
```

**コード**

```
def LoadModel(path, input_shape):
    params = None
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        params = json.load(f)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(
        params[0]['nOutputPlane'],
        params[0]['kH'],
        params[0]['kW'],
        border_mode='same',
        weights=params[0]['weight'],
        bias=params[0]['bias'],
        input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.1))
    for param in params[1:]:
        model.add(Convolution2D(param['nOutputPlane'], param['kH'], param['kW'], border_mode='same', weights=param['weight'], bias=param['bias']))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(0.1))

    return model
```

input_shape = (1, [高さ], [幅])
カーネルサイズ3x3です。
最初のweightのサイズ = (32, 3, 3)
最初のaddでエラーが出ます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def LoadModel(path, input_shape):
    params = None
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        params = json.load(f)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(
        params[0]['nOutputPlane'],
        params[0]['kH'],
        params[0]['kW'],
        init='zero',
        border_mode='same',
        weights=[np.array(params[0]['weight']), np.array(params[0]['bias'])],
        bias=True,
        input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.1))
    for param in params[1:]:
        model.add(Convolution2D(
            param['nOutputPlane'],
            param['kH'],
            param['kW'],
            init='zero',
            border_mode='same',
            weights=[np.array(param['weight']), np.array(param['bias'])],
            bias=True))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(0.1))

    return model
```